# Use environment variables to identify a directory in Powershell

Tags: powershell

New to Powershell.

In a Powershell script, I'm trying to create a directory using the domain and user name as pulled from environment variables.  So for domain\user "FOOBAR\kilroy" I want to create something like c:\Users\FOOBAR_kilroy.

I've tried

```
"c:\Users\$(env:UserDomain)"+"_"+"$(env:UserName)"; 
"c:\Users\$env:UserDomain"+"_"+"$env:UserName"; and 
"c:\Users\env:UserDomain_$(env:UserName)".
```

All the above generate an error.

What am I missing?

Comment: The one combination you *didn’t* try is ```$($env:UserDomain)``` :-).

Comment: Your second option works: `"c:\Users\$env:UserDomain"+"_"+"$env:UserName"`. Without seeing the error we won't be able to tell you why it wasn't working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

- You can embed even *namespace-qualified* variable references such as `$env:USERDOMAIN` *as-is*.

  - Enclosure in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) is only needed for *expressions and commands*, such as `$($env:USERDOMAIN.Length)`, `$($args[0])`, `$(1 + 2)`, or `$(Get-Date)` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's string interpolation.
- However, as with any embedded variable reference, enclosure of the (potentially namespace-qualified) name in `{...}` (e.g. `${env:USERDOMAIN}`) may be necessary in order to disambiguate variable names from *subsequent characters*, such as `_` in your case, given that `_` is a character that can be part of a PowerShell variable name *without* enclosure in `{...}`.

Therefore:

```
"c:\Users\${env:USERDOMAIN}_$env:USERNAME"
```